# how to set a default value for a model's attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, modelform

I created a model and then model-form to take input from user. I am trying to set the default value of the author to the active user's name, but instead, the default value is set to the username of admin. Please take a look at the code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime

class tweets(models.Model):
    def curr_user():
        for user in User.objects.all():
            if user.is_active:
                return user.get_username
    z = curr_user()
    k = datetime.now
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default=z)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default = k)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import tweets

class TweetsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
            model = tweets
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which user is logged (I'm guessing it's the admin) to check this easily go to 'localhost:8000/admin' (only works in local), then logout and login with the user "autor"

Comment: I have checked the active user. It's displaying the admin's username even when other users are logged in.